# Merge elements of array based on index position or id

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a list array which I'm getting from the database. I want to create a new List with all elements in the array grouped by their index position or id.

This is the array I'm working with:

```
[
    {
        "content": "Content A1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "content": "Content A2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "content": "Content A3",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "content": "Content A4",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "content": "Content A5",
        "id": 5
    }
]

[
    {
        "content": "Content B1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "content": "Content B2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "content": "Content B3",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "content": "Content B4",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "content": "Content B5",
        "id": 5
    }
]

[
    {
        "content": "Content C1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "content": "Content C2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "content": "Content C3",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "content": "Content C4",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "content": "Content C5",
        "id": 5
    }
]
```

This is how I want the new List array to look like:

```
[
{
     "content": {"Content A1","Content B1","Content C1"}
     "id": 1
},
{
     "content": {"Content A2", "Content B2", "Content C2"}
     "id": 2
},
{
     "content": {"Content A3","Content B3","Content C3"}
     "id": 3
},
{
     "content": {"Content A4","Content B4","Content C4"}
     "id": 4
},
{
     "content": {"Content A5","Content B5","Content C5"}
     "id": 5
}
]
```

I have tried this code but it returns only the last object:

```
  List<String> contentArray = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < b.listDetail.size(); i++) {
                int finalI = i;
                contentArray = listResource.stream()
                        .map(a -> a.listDetail.get(finalI).content)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
              
   }
  System.out.println(contentArray);
```

Comment: So are you merging 3 arrays or n arrays?

Comment: @cela, n arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, just need to store contentArray in a list for all index.

```
  List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < b.listDetail.size(); i++) {
       int finalI = i;
       List<String> contentArray = listResource.stream()
                        .map(a -> a.listDetail.get(finalI).content)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
       res.add(contentArray); // store all contents for a index in list
  }
```

You can create a class for your response with `id` and `contents` and construct inside loop and add in the list.